# Athenian tribute lists

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece, classical-antiquity, classical-greece, athens

Who were the Athenian tributes in the 434/433 and 430/29 periods?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for sources.

Comment: You are a bad man because you asked for sources. Read the help.

Comment: Also, the request is trivial. Have you heard of Google? Seriously.

Comment: This seems to be it: http://books.google.co.il/books?id=1PCnzm6oBhMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Hi, Felix. Unfortunately the only list translated in that book is for 450 BC. Thanks for nice reply though :)

Comment: @Brasidas I can't find any information about such a specific detail, but they have a good chunk of books you can buy. They might answer your question.

Comment: I'll try to look up Meritt's books tomorrow. Any particular city you are interested in?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg All the cities documented for 434/433 and 430/429 BC with the assigned tribute for each, if it's not too much.

Comment: I am sorry to report that I failed in my self-appointed task. I did find Meritt's book but it seems to be organized in a way that is too difficult for a layman such as me to navigate. There are hundreds of pages with tribute lists but they are organized alphabetically (in Greek, no English translations are given, it seems) and not chronologically. I also did not find a chronological index. So to compile from the tables there a list such as you require would take far far more time than I can spare, alas.

Comment: If there is a pointer to another publication that has the information in more accessible form, I can look it up the library for you.

Comment: That's what I've found: apparently there's no easy resource for this. Thanks for the effort, @FelixGoldberg

Comment: But perhaps you might want to contact Bjorn Paarman (the link given by theodox in the comment to his answer mentions him) - he sounds like the go-to person for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe some of the lists - at least fragmentary ones from epigraphic sources - can be found in Fornara's volume in the  "Translated Documents of Greece and Rome" series:

http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/classical-studies/ancient-history/archaic-times-end-peloponnesian-war-2nd-edition

Comment: Got a copy of this book. Very promising title, and has a lot of info on tributes, but ATL fragments only for 454/3 and 425/4 B.C periods.

Comment: This looks like it might be useful:http://eer.hypotheses.org/20